# Show updated DataFrame every 5 seconds

Tags: python, pandas, list, dataframe, concatenation

I want to show a dataframe that is updated every 5 seconds. I can show a list every 5 seconds, but I can not manage to concat it to a dataframe.

Here is my code:

```
tradeslist = []

for symbol in symbols:
    df = pd.read_sql(symbol, engine, index_col='Date')
    df.Close = df['Adj Close']
    applyindicators(df)
    conditions(df)
    trades = matchtrades(df)
    tradeslist.append(trades)

tradesdf = pd.concat(tradeslist)

tradesdf

def show_frame():
        
        tradesdf
        
schedule.every(4).seconds.do(show_frame)

while 1:
    schedule.run_pending()
    time.sleep(1)
```

Comment: You are just showing the same dataframe every time.  If you want the dataframe to change, then you have to fetch the new data first.  That means your `for` loop has to be in the function you call.  Also note that saying `tradesdf` only works inside a Jupyter notebook.  It does nothing at all when run as a script.  It's a bad habit; you should start using `print`.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.